# List labels on left with Arabic using polyglossia

Tags: enumerate, polyglossia, arabic

I am using `polyglossia` with English as the main language and Arabic as the other language. I have an `enumerate` list with the first content of the list being in Arabic followed by a translation in English. The problem is that the number label of the list is on the right as opposed to the left; the latter being my requirement.

Adding a non-breaking space right after `\item` helps but messes up the alignment.

Here is my MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[
Script=Arabic,%
Numbers=Proportional,%
Scale=1.5%
]{Traditional Arabic}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \begin{Arabic}
        اَلحَمدُ لِلهِ الَّذِي أحيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أمَاتَنَا وَ إِلَيهِ
        النُّشُورُ
\end{Arabic}

  Praise is to Allāh Who gives us life after He has caused us to die and
to Him is the return.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here is the current output,

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your `Arabic` environment within a `parbox`

```
\item 
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
\begin{Arabic}
        اَلحَمدُ لِلهِ الَّذِي أحيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أمَاتَنَا وَ إِلَيهِ
        النُّشُورُ
\end{Arabic}}
```

A new environment can be used here to simplify code and avoid repeating `\parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[
Script=Arabic,%
Numbers=Proportional,%
Scale=1.5%
]{Traditional Arabic}

\newenvironment{Arabicitem}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{Arabic}}
{\end{Arabic}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \begin{Arabicitem}
        اَلحَمدُ لِلهِ الَّذِي أحيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أمَاتَنَا وَ إِلَيهِ
        النُّشُورُ
\end{Arabicitem}

  Praise is to Allāh Who gives us life after He has caused us to die and
to Him is the return.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can automate this?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Is it possible to align the number with the first line of Arabic text if a paragraph of Arabic text is used? Right now, it centers the number vertically which looks odd.