# Align enumerate label with minipage content in its items

Tags: enumerate, minipage, polyglossia, arabic, parbox

This question is based on my previous question, [List labels on left with Arabic using Polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355193/list-labels-on-left-with-arabic-using-polyglossia), however, it can be read by itself as well.

NOTE: You will have to use XeLaTeX and probably change the Arabic font if you are not using Windows.

I have the following MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[
Script=Arabic,%
Scale=1.5%
]{Traditional Arabic}

\newenvironment{Arabicitem}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{Arabic}}
{\end{Arabic}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \parbox[t][][t]{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
  \item
  \begin{Arabicitem}اللَّهُمَّ بَاعِدْ بَيْنِي وَبَيْنَ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا بَاعَدْتَ بَيْنَ الْمَشْرِقِ وَالْمَغْرِبِ، اللَّهُمَّ نَقِّنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا يُنَقَّى الثَّوْبُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الدَّنَسِ، اللَّهُمَّ اغْسِلْنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ بِالثَّلْجِ وَالْمَاءِ وَالْبَرَد.\end{Arabicitem}

  ``O Allāh! Separate me (far) from my sins as you have separated (far) the East and West. O Allāh! Cleanse me of my sins as white cloth is cleansed from dirt. O Allāh! Wash me of my sins with water, ice, and snow.'' He used to say this in obligatory prayers.\footnote{Abū Dāwūd and al-Ḥākim, who declared it \emph{ṣaḥīḥ} and al-Dhahabī concurred.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which generates the following,

[image: MWE output]

My problem is the alignment of the `enumerate` label with the `minipage`. I was able to fix this when using a `parbox` by using the `t` option.

I have tried doing the same for the `minipage` environment by changing the first argument of the `newenvironment` command to:

```
\newenvironment{Arabicitem}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\begin{Arabic}}
```

However, this made the label higher than the Arabic text as shown below.

[image: MWE Edited output]

How can I fix this so that the label is aligned with the first line of Arabic as is the case for the `lipsum` item?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. You can upvote it as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be other solutions, but the simplest trick I can think of is to put `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` in the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[
Script=Arabic,%
Scale=1.5%
]{Traditional Arabic}

\newenvironment{Arabicitem}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{Arabic}}
    {\end{Arabic}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \parbox[t][][t]{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
  \item  \begin{Arabicitem}اللَّهُمَّ بَاعِدْ بَيْنِي وَبَيْنَ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا بَاعَدْتَ بَيْنَ الْمَشْرِقِ وَالْمَغْرِبِ، اللَّهُمَّ نَقِّنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا يُنَقَّى الثَّوْبُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الدَّنَسِ، اللَّهُمَّ اغْسِلْنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ بِالثَّلْجِ وَالْمَاءِ وَالْبَرَد.\end{Arabicitem}

  ``O Allāh! Separate me (far) from my sins as you have separated (far) the East and West. O Allāh! Cleanse me of my sins as white cloth is cleansed from dirt. O Allāh! Wash me of my sins with water, ice, and snow.'' He used to say this in obligatory prayers.\footnote{Abū Dāwūd and al-Ḥākim, who declared it \emph{ṣaḥīḥ} and al-Dhahabī concurred.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using a minipage at all. Beside this: The main point is to start the paragraph with \leavevmode before switching the language:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[
Script=Arabic,%
Scale=1.5%
]%{Traditional Arabic}
 {Arial Unicode MS}

\newenvironment{ArabicitemA}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\leavevmode\otherlanguage{arabic}}
{\end{minipage}}

\newenvironment{ArabicitemB}{\leavevmode\otherlanguage{arabic}}
{}

\newenvironment{ArabicitemC}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\leavevmode\begin{Arabic}}
{\end{Arabic}\end{minipage}}

\newenvironment{ArabicitemD}{\leavevmode\begin{Arabic}}
{\end{Arabic}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
  \item
  \begin{ArabicitemA}اللَّهُمَّ بَاعِدْ بَيْنِي وَبَيْنَ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا بَاعَدْتَ بَيْنَ الْمَشْرِقِ وَالْمَغْرِبِ، اللَّهُمَّ نَقِّنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا يُنَقَّى الثَّوْبُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الدَّنَسِ، اللَّهُمَّ اغْسِلْنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ بِالثَّلْجِ وَالْمَاءِ وَالْبَرَد.\end{ArabicitemA}

  \item 
  \begin{ArabicitemB}اللَّهُمَّ بَاعِدْ بَيْنِي وَبَيْنَ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا بَاعَدْتَ بَيْنَ الْمَشْرِقِ وَالْمَغْرِبِ، اللَّهُمَّ نَقِّنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا يُنَقَّى الثَّوْبُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الدَّنَسِ، اللَّهُمَّ اغْسِلْنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ بِالثَّلْجِ وَالْمَاءِ وَالْبَرَد.\end{ArabicitemB}

  \item
  \begin{ArabicitemC}اللَّهُمَّ بَاعِدْ بَيْنِي وَبَيْنَ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا بَاعَدْتَ بَيْنَ الْمَشْرِقِ وَالْمَغْرِبِ، اللَّهُمَّ نَقِّنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا يُنَقَّى الثَّوْبُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الدَّنَسِ، اللَّهُمَّ اغْسِلْنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ بِالثَّلْجِ وَالْمَاءِ وَالْبَرَد.\end{ArabicitemC}

    \item
  \begin{ArabicitemD}اللَّهُمَّ بَاعِدْ بَيْنِي وَبَيْنَ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا بَاعَدْتَ بَيْنَ الْمَشْرِقِ وَالْمَغْرِبِ، اللَّهُمَّ نَقِّنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ، كَمَا يُنَقَّى الثَّوْبُ الأَبْيَضُ مِنَ الدَّنَسِ، اللَّهُمَّ اغْسِلْنِي مِنْ خَطَايَايَ بِالثَّلْجِ وَالْمَاءِ وَالْبَرَد.\end{ArabicitemD}


\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Btw: I wonder if "you have separated (far) the East and West" is the suitable quote for a site like this where east and west are quite near.

Comment: What do you recommend besides minipage?

Comment: None of your solutions work for Arabic as it has to be right-aligned.

Comment: If you want a full arabic paragraph why do you want the number to be on the left side? That leads to conflicting paragraph settings. I don't see a necessity for a box, or do you want to suppress pagebreaks inside the text? But if you want numbers left then you will have to do something like `\item\leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}`.

Comment: The main language of the document is in English. The list item is in Arabic followed by its translation.

Comment: I do understand this, but this means that the paragraph should now be at the same time left-to-right (for the number) and right-to-left (for the arabic) and so you get problems and negative vspace is probably the only way to get around it, even if it is ugly.